# How to get the swiftui drop delegate to be called

Tags: swiftui, drag-and-drop, ios14

I hope you can help.
I'm trying to implement a drag and drop of plain text in SwiftUI on iOS 14.
The text is being dragged from a browser and dropped onto a TextEditor. The text is being dragged ok and it appears in the TextEditor when dropped, but the delegate function is not being called.

If you have any ideas or where I can look for an answer, I'd be very appreciative.

My code is basically this:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var entityText = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {

            TextEditor(text: $entityText)
                .onDrop(of: [.text], delegate: MyDropDelegate())
                .border(Color.black, width: 1)
                .padding( 60.0)
        }
    }
}

struct MyDropDelegate: DropDelegate {
    
    init() {
        print("*** INIT ")
    }
    
    func performDrop(info: DropInfo) -> Bool {
        print("*** Dropped \(info)")
        guard info.hasItemsConforming(to: [.text]) else {
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
    
    func validateDrop(info: DropInfo) -> Bool {
        print("*** Validate")
        return info.hasItemsConforming(to: [.text])
    }
    
    func dropEntered(info: DropInfo) {
        print("*** ENTERED")
    }
}
```

Comment: TextEditor probably does its own drag and drop handling, just as it supports cut/copy/paste keyboard commands automatically. If so, you don’t need onDrop at all.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Adam. Yes it does do it’s own drop handling in that the variable gets populated but I really wanted the delegate event to do something. Never mind, I have decided to changes my plans and work on without it. I’ll figure it out one day. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

As [Adam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1601849/adam) mentioned in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67494572/how-to-get-the-swiftui-drop-delegate-to-be-called/67495848#comment119300041_67494572), the TextEditor might conflict. But the Delegate should be set to self or an observable object. You're instantiating something for a parameter that expects a reference.

Comment: Thanks for your respose @Ryan. I was unable to get it working so I decided to change my design a bit and not use a delegate. I’ll try again another day. Thanks very much.